# How do you install the MAAS Image Builder on 14.04 LTS

Tags: maas

I have followed the instructions here:

https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/os-support.html#generated-images-vs-custom-images

After running these commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maas-maintainers/stable
sudo apt-get install maas-image-builder
```

I got following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package maas-image-builder
```

Any help? Much appreciated!

Comment: Before installing run `sudo apt-get update`, maybe help you.

Comment: Yes, this was already done. Up to date, still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Rough steps I followed to get it working.  Note it doesn't appear that the image builder is in the main areas or at least I had issues with that.  Some of these steps MAY not be necessary.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo apt-get bzr
sudo apt-get -y install make python-virtualenv
bzr -Ossl.cert_reqs=none branch lp:maas-image-builder

cd maas-image-builder
make install-dependencies
make
sudo ./bin/maas-image-builder -o centos7-amd64-root-tgz centos
sudo ./bin/maas-image-builder -o centos6-amd64-root-tgz centos --edition 6
```