# Ubuntu MAAS - How to covert my iso file to bootable tgz

Tags: windows-7, maas

in maas have installed 2.6 stable using ppa and i can able to add machines by using ubuntu images which is given by maas by default
my question is i have a windows7.iso file and how can i use ?
its supports the below filetypes 
:param filetype: Optional.  Filetype for uploaded
content. (Default: `tgz`. Supported: `tgz`, `ddtgz`, `ddtbz`,
`ddtxz`, `ddtar`, `ddbz2`, `ddgz`, `ddxz`, `ddraw`)
:type filetype: String

tried to covering the iso file by using the below wiki

- https://www.tecmint.com/extract-files-from-iso-files-linux/
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-convert-tgz-to-img-802900/

but not working as expected can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.maas.io/2.6/en/installconfig-images

"Ubuntu Advantage is needed to use Windows, RHEL and ESXi images to build a custom image for any operating system."

Looking at https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage-service-description#uasd-maas-support

2.2 Support for the tooling required to convert certified operating system images not provided by Canonical into MAAS images.

2.3 Licence to use MAAS Image Builder.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! 

i have tried to configure maas-image-builder but getting the following error "E: Unable to locate package maas-image-builder"
Refer this site
https://askubuntu.com/questions/744966/how-do-you-install-the-maas-image-builder-on-14-04-lts
seems it's supports version 1.9
can you please guide me

Comment: You need to have a support contract as per https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage-service-description#uasd-maas-support  and will be given access to Maas image builder.

Comment: Thanks!! Will check